# NAs introduced by coercion in function to capture mean, median, variance, sd, mode, range

Tags: r

**Problem**

Issue with simple data.frame in R to capture vital statistics not using built in summary() function.

My idea was to capture each statistic, sd, mean, var, etc, and add to variables c(attribute, mean, median, variance, sd, mode, range). Then add rows in a function, but when executed, received 'NAs introduced by coercion'. Validated and checked that  df_survey[[col]] was actually pulled individual values OK. And was able to compute mean, median, etc for [[col]] individually ok. NA's type conversion? Missing something related to type conversion. Need some advise.

```
data <- c(attribute, mean, median, variance, sd, mode, range)
df_stats[nrow(data) + 1, ] <- data()
```

**Error**

```
Warning messages:
1: In df_add_row(n, i) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In df_add_row(n, i) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In df_add_row(n, i) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In df_add_row(n, i) : NAs introduced by coercion
5: In df_add_row(n, i) : NAs introduced by coercion
6: In df_add_row(n, i) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

**Code**

```
df_stats <- data.frame (
  Attribute = "",
  Mean = "",
  Median = "",
  Variance = "",
  SD = "",
  Mode = "",
  Range = ""
)

df_add_row = function(col, i) {
  attribute = col
  mean = as.numeric(mean(df_survey[[col]]))
  median = as.numeric(median(df_survey[[col]]))
  variance = as.numeric(var(df_survey[[col]]))
  sd = as.numeric(sd(df_survey[[col]]))
  mode = as.numeric(mode(df_survey[[col]]))
  range = as.numeric(range(df_survey[[col]]))
  data <- c(attribute, mean, median, variance, sd, mode, range)                              
  df_stats[nrow(data) + 1, ] <- data()    
}

cols_of_survey = colnames(df_survey)
i=1
for (n in cols_of_survey) {
  df_add_row(n, i)
  i=i+1
}
```

Comment: Not related to the error but the base `mode` function is nothing to do with the statistical definition of the mode.

Comment: True, model is not needed, I just wanted to include it for completeness